# Using namespaces in TinyDB in App Inventor

Tags: app-inventor

I am building an app to store information of clients and their PCs and errors of PCs. When I submit the first client and error and after that another client, the app spits out an error message.

I read something about namespaces, but I can not figure out how to use them.

[image: This image shows adding new clients.]

[image: This image shows displaying clients]

[image: This image shows adding and displaying errors]

When I try to display the clients the error message displays:

[image]

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using multiple tinyDB instences I had to set different namespaces for each one. Otherwise the data will intertwine.

Answer (score 1):

As the error message is trying to tell you: you are using a **Select list item** block and you are trying to select the second item of a list, which does only have one item. That item is *err-velka*.

Find all Select list item blocks in your code and check, if you are trying to select a second item from the list... Then use **Do it** to debug our blocks, see also tip 4 here https://puravidaapps.com/learn.php